# cannot set DOM element to a variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set a DOM element to a variable but when I console.log() the variable, it shows null.

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
console.log(canvas); //null
```

but it is working perfect in the tutorial I'm following. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If it is null it can't find the element. You are probably calling the code too soon, ie before the element is created

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you shared so if you want a specific answer you'll probably need to share more. What does your HTML look like? Where is the script called?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] so we can verify it. Nothing wrong with the code shown except not enough context provided

Comment: @sumeetkumar He's not targeting a class or ID, but the element.

Comment: Is 'canvas' a custom tag if it is true you should be got element. Can you share html code in here

Comment: @Niladri, ngOninit is an Angular called hook, nothing in the question has anything to do with Angular

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ Custom tag? `<canvas>` is a standard HTML5 tag.

Comment: Sorry it is my fault

Comment: @PatrickEvans wrong comment on wrong question :)

Answer (score 0):

Due to [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), `querySelector()` returns null if no matches are found. So you have no `canvas` nodes in the moment you are trying to get it. You should

- make sure that your html document has `canvas` node
- make sure that you run your script after the `canvas` node is set to the html document

The following html code will work for sure

```
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        console.log(canvas);
    </script>
```